# If $T$ is an operator such that $T^2 = \lambda T$, and $\|Tx\| = \|x\|$ for some $x \neq 0$, then prove $\lambda = \pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $\mathbb R^n$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $T^2=\lambda T$ for some non zero $\lambda $ in $\mathbb R.$ If $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for some non zero vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ then prove that $\lambda = \pm 1$.

If $x$ is an eigenvector then the result is easily proved by me. How do I prove the result for $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ which is not an eigenvector? Please help.

Comment: There are also counterexamples with $T\ne0$.

Comment: $T = 0$ is not a counterexample, because there is no non-zero $x$ such that $\|Tx\| = \|x\|$, though Angina Seng is right. Any non-zero operator $T$ satisfying $T^2 = \lambda T$, where $|\lambda| > 1$ will form a counterexample (provided $n > 1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume $\|\ \|$ is the usual Euclidean norm. Consider the matrix
$$T=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}.$$
Then $T^2=2T$ but $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for
$$x=\pmatrix{1\\\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: You are right. Euclidean norm is used here.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have been trying hard to prove this result because it’s given to be true in a competitive examination.